# Equation for an ellipsoid for a general minor axis

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

Suppose I have an ellipsoid with the minor axis along $z$ axis on the sphere, then the ellipsoid equation is
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1.
$$
Here $a$, $b$ and $c$ are chosen such that ellipsoid remains inside the sphere.
What would be the equation for ellipsoid if the minor axis is not along $z$ axis but along some $(\theta,\phi)$ axis (here $\theta$ is the polar angle with $z$ axis and $\phi$ is the azimuthal angle with $x$ axis).

Comment: Just apply a rotation to this equation.

Comment: If there's only one minor axis (for example, an ellipsoid model of the Earth) then you can set $b = a$.